# What should I add behind the Trade Name for my Sole Proprietorship?

Tags: terms-of-service, corporate-law, legal-terms, india, trade-name

I am registered as a **Sole Proprietorship** in India to do business.

I have provided a **Trade Name** eg. ABC

So I have 2 questions:

1. In my Terms of Service and any other legal document can I use the **Trade Name** eg.

   > "These terms are between you and ABC"

   Or could I use **My Own Name rather then the Trade Name.**
2. What could I add behind ABC? for example with LLC's you add ABC LLC.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strictly correct answer. If you are worried about confusion as might be the case in a business name like ABC such as ABC - a diner, and ABC - an auto repair shop both geographically close to each other where both just go by the name ABC then you could use the business's address to differentiate your business from the other. Alternatively you could use your real name with your company's fictitious name for example: *john Doe dba ABC* (dba - doing business as) as is common in franchises. With this you could again, also include the business address to further prevent confusion.

Comment: I am going to create a website. And the website will have a Terms of Use page. So there should I write something like this - Full Name dba Firm Name ("we", "us", "our"). For example you can see the Google Terms Of Use - The Services are provided by Google LLC (“Google”)

Comment: @Raj Unfortunately "Should" is a solicitation for legal advise, which I cannot provide.

Answer (score 0):

It would be improper to add anything to the trade name (e.g. LLC or Inc. or Ltd.) other than TM. You would be giving the impression that you are an entity when you are not.

You can use the trade name in your TOS but should define it somewhere to be the trade name of your real name.